# Java - cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, class

Here's my simple class:

```
public class Project {
    private int size;
    private Obj tree;
    static Obj insert( Obj t, String s ) { // t is null
        t = new Obj();
        t.val = s;
        return t;
    }
    public Project()
    {
      Obj tree = new Obj();
      int size=0;
    }
    public class Obj
    {
      public String val;
      public Obj()
      {
        val=null;
      }
    }     
}
```

However, when I try to create a new object in the insert() function, I get this error:

```
Error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Obj` class is not `static` == it's an inner class.  This means that it needs an instance of the enclosing class `Project` to live.

From the `static` method `insert`, there is no such `Project` instance, hence the compiler error.

The `Obj` class doesn't seem to need any instance variables in `Project`, so there is no reason to keep it non-`static`.  Make the `Obj` class `static` in `Project`.

```
public static class Obj
```

Comment: Aha, thank you a lot. I'll mark your answer when I can.